# Nested forEach does not work as expected in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, foreach

I'm having a problem with this function, which should work the same way as Lodash [_.zip([arrays])](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#zip)

In a nutshell, `zip(['a', 'b'], [1, 2], [true, false]);` shall return `[['a', 1, true], ['b', 2, false]]`

**My function:**

```
function zip(...array) {
  const newArr = Array(array[0].length).fill([]);
  array.forEach((el, i) => {
    el.forEach((item, idx) => {
      //   newArr[idx][i] = item;
      newArr[idx].push(item);
    });
  });
  return newArr;
}
```

**Instead, it returns:**  `[ [ 'a', 'b', 1, 2, true, false ], [ 'a', 'b', 1, 2, true, false ] ]`

What could be written wrong?

Comment: What does stepping through the code in a debugger show?

Comment: You are using the spread operator on the array input. This will expand each item of the array into a separate argument. I don’t think this is the functionality you are wanting here as you are trying to use that same input as an array. Try removing the spread operator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `fill` you are filling the array with the same array, so when you push to the array at index 0, you are also pushing to the array at index 1. You can solve this by first filling the array, then calling `map`.

You should also be looping through each item in the new array, then looping through each parameter and getting the item at the index of the outer loop.

```js
function zip(...array) {
  const newArr = Array(array[0].length).fill().map(u => ([]));
  newArr.forEach((item, i) => {
    array.forEach((a) => {
      item.push(a[i])
    })
  })
  return newArr;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(zip(['a', 'b'], [1, 2], [true, false])))
```